# sorting the list and showing list in grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

I am trying to write a linq query as below in which I am getting the product list

```
DBEntities _context = null;
List<BOMViewModel> lstBOM;  
using (_context = new DBEntities())
{
   ObjectSet<BOMProduct> objBOMProduct = _context.BOMProducts;
   ObjectSet<BOMComponent> objBOMComponent = _context.BOMComponents;
   ObjectSet<Product> objProducts = _context.Products;
     lstBOM = (from BOMProduct in objBOMProduct 
               join BOMComponent in objBOMComponent on BOMProduct.BOMProductKey equals BOMComponent.BOMProductKey
               join products in objProducts on BOMComponent.ProductKey equals products.ProductKey
               where (BOMProduct.LengthKey == 39 )
               select new BOMViewModel
               {
                      ProductKey = BOMComponent.ProductKey,
                      ProductPN = products.ProductPartNum,
                      ProductDesc = products.ProductDesc,
                      ProductPrice = products.ProductPrice,
                      Quantity = BOMComponent.BOMComponentQuantity
                }).ToList();
}
return lstBOM;
```

This list I am binding to Grid and displaying the data in grid, all the working good enough.

In database I have few products desc. which contains 'Header' some desc. contains 'Hdr' I want to show them first from the list then rest other product need to show. you can say I want to sort then by 'Header' or 'Hdr'.

Suppose I have 25 items in list, in that 10 items description contains 'Header' and 5 itmes description contrains 'Hdr' and rest 10 does not contain both the word. then in grd it should show items which contain 'Header' then 'hdr' item then rest other items

How is that possible??? Please someone suggest some exp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one way although it might not be the best. You can do a conditional statement inside the query e.g

```
.OrderBy(x => x.ProductDesc == "Header" ? 1 : x.ProductDesc == "Hdr" ? 2 : 3)
```